# QColorPicker with bright slider

Tags: qt, qt5, qcolor, qcolordialog

When I open a QColorPicker, I click in the coloor map in the top center, and select any color (lets say red) this color appears as black in the selected color bar bottom center.

I have to move additionally the slider on the top right (see red arrow)  [image]
to its top position, to approach the selected color. Why is this slider not initially set to the highest value, so I do not see black always?

Comment: Set it to the desired position yourself. Every parameter is default set to 0 I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation it refers to the [Standard Dialogs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-standarddialogs-dialog-cpp.html) example:

```
void Dialog::setColor()
{
    const QColorDialog::ColorDialogOptions options = QFlag(colorDialogOptionsWidget->value());
    const QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::green, this, "Select Color", options);

    if (color.isValid()) {
        colorLabel->setText(color.name());
        colorLabel->setPalette(QPalette(color));
        colorLabel->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    }
}
```

Note in `QColorDialog::getColor` how it specifies an initial color.  This should set the brightness bar for you.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolordialog.html#getColor

```
QColor QColorDialog::getColor(const QColor & initial = Qt::white, QWidget * parent = 0, const QString & title = QString(), ColorDialogOptions options = 0)
```

Hope that helps.